# Android unparsaeble date

Tags: android, string, sqlite, date

I'm trying to convert a string to add to the calendar. I get parsing error.

```
GregorianCalendar dateAndTime = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );

        try {
            dateAndTime.setTime(sdf.parse(mBtnPickDate.getText().toString()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

        String strDate = sdf.format( dateAndTime );
```

Comment: what is your input???

Answer (score 0):

Uhh... yeah.

If, for instance, the (presumably `TextView`) `mBtnPickDate` contains the string "this is not a date", you will, obviously, get a parsing error.  What else could possibly happen!?

Unless the view contains a string that looks like 2014-02-14, you will, of course, get the exception.  So catch it and post a toast that says something like "Please enter a date in the format: YYYY-MM-DD".